# Desktop application API access through Web application

Tags: c++, node.js, api, web-applications, desktop-application

I have a desktop application written in C++. That application also have some apis written for some general purposes like:- fetching list , etc.

Currently the application is installed on various systems and there is a single main server on which data gets stored.

Issue is user can not access the data using different locations.

Now we are planning to move it on web so that user can access data from anywhere in the world.

So, is it possible to access the desktop application api using the web application?

When we open the website then it will also open the desktop application on the desktop then after login we would like to access the apis written in desktop application and show the data in web app.

Any help would be highly appreciable!

Comment: Can you give more details about the cpp `API`? What is the protocol that is being used (IPC, TCP, HTTP, etc)

Comment: @Daniel it is a desktop based application and hence not connected to internet as of now.

Comment: But what is the `API` referring to in this sentence ? `That application also have some apis written for some general purposes like:- fetching list , etc.`. Can application on the same host use this API?

Comment: The API i am referring to are some set of endpoints which application use to access details. Yes application on the same host can use these APIs.

Answer (score 0):

As I just understood you have an Desktop application on multiple systems and you want to have access to the same data? Right?
So you have multiple options in that case. A very simple way is to install a database on a server (like mysql) and connect the app directly to that database. Than you can easily write/read/update/delete data from that db. Also you can write an API on that server with the database and fetch the data over that web api with your application.

Comment: thanks for you answer. Yes, i have a desktop based application and i would like a web based application as well. So what i want is , whenever i open my web application in the same desktop on which desktop application is installed and opened then my web app can hit desktop app api and fetch data from it.